# SQLAlchemy create multi column index using naming_convention

Tags: indexing, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to create multi (i.e. 2-column index) for a model based table. But I'd like not to give specific name for this index. I'd like that `naming_convention` and `alembic revision --autogenerate` would do it's job with naming index. So far I have code like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
from sqlalchemy.schema import Index

metadata = MetaData(
        naming_convention={
            'pk': '%(table_name)s_pk',
            'ix': '%(table_name)s_%(column_0_N_name)s_ix',
        },
    )

@as_declarative(metadata=metadata)
class Base:
    pass

class Foo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col1 = Column('Col1', Integer)
    col2 = Column('Col2', DateTime)

Index(
    metadata.naming_convention['ix'] % {
        'table_name': Foo.__tablename__,
        'column_0_N_name': Foo.col1.expression.name + "_" + Foo.col2.expression.name
    },
    Foo.col1,
    Foo.col2,
)
```

So I'd like to avoid the 'creating name' part of code:

```
    metadata.naming_convention['ix'] % {
        'table_name': Foo.__tablename__,
        'column_0_N_name': Foo.col1.expression.name + "_" + Foo.col2.expression.name
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after more search there is very simple solution. According to [github comment in SQLAlchemy issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4289#issuecomment-441942083) if you would like to create index by `Index()` you silmply need to pass `name=None` argument, and fill arguments for columns.

so the code above should look like (part that stays the same):

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
from sqlalchemy.schema import Index

metadata = MetaData(
        naming_convention={
            'pk': '%(table_name)s_pk',
            'ix': '%(table_name)s_%(column_0_N_name)s_ix',
        },
    )

@as_declarative(metadata=metadata)
class Base:
    pass
```

Option 1 (declare multi column index out of table model)

```
class Foo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col1 = Column('Col1', Integer)
    col2 = Column('Col2', DateTime)

Index(None, Foo.col1, Foo.col2)
```

Option 2 (declare multi column index inside of table model)

```
class Foo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col1 = Column('Col1', Integer)
    col2 = Column('Col2', DateTime)
    __table_args__ = (
        Index(None, 'Col1', 'Col2'),
    )
```

Then index name (in both options) would be:

```
Foo_Col1_Col2_ix
```

I have not found this kind of solution in SQLALchemy documentation (maybe there is?), but it's good that there are some answers on github issues in SQLAlchemy github :)